# WPF custom shader effect property binding for animation

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

I'm implementing transitions in a WPF application.

First I "save" my 2 FrameworkElement in 2 ImageBrush.
Then I set the Input & Back (Brush) properties of my shader Effect with them.

```cs
    CustomEffect s = new CustomEffect();

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)SourceFrameWorkElement.ActualWidth, (int)SourceFrameWorkElement.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    rtb.Render(SourceFrameWorkElement);
    ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(rtb);
    s.Input = ib;

    rtb.Render(TargetFrameWorkElement);
    ib.ImageSource = rtb;
    s.Back = ib;

    SourceFrameWorkElement.Effect = s;
```

Now that all is set up, I want to animate the Time property of my shader, and i've tried this:

```
    DoubleAnimation refDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, Duration);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(refDoubleAnimation, SourceFrameWorkElement);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(refDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Effect).(CustomEffect.Time)");
    refStoryboard.Children.Add(refDoubleAnimation);
    refStoryboard.Completed += new EventHandler(OnStoryboardCompleted);
    refStoryboard.Begin(SourceFrameWorkElement, true);
```

and i get an InvalidOperationException on the begin method with this message:

> "Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(Effect).(CustomEffect.Time)'.
>   Verify that applicable objects supports the properties."

But when I use a built in Effect like BlurEffect, it works....

Can someone tell me where i'm wrong ?

**Edit:**
I've also tried

```
    SourceElement.Effect.BeginAnimation(SlideInEffect.TimeProperty, refDoubleAnimation)
```

instead of using the storyboard, I don't get an exception but the second image pop instantly and the animation is not playing

Comment: does your CustomEffect have a DependencyProperty "Time"?

Comment: maybe try to set the propertypath more explicitely (FrameworkElement.Effect).(CustomEffect.Time). also check that your Time DP adheres to conventions (dp as well as clr setter, dp string the same as clr setter name, DP with ...Property suffix, and so on)

Comment: i've checked and my properties are named properly.
i've tested with (FrameWorkElement.Effect).(CustomEffect.Time) and (UIElement.Effect).(CustomEffect.Time) and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use BeginAnimation ^^

In fact, I had the second image with opacity to 1, and the animation was playing behind
(i checked if the time elapsed to get in my OnAnimationCompleted eventHandler matched with the transition Duration)

so i've created a second animation on the TargetElement opacity with 2 DiscreteDoubleKeyFrames to do the trick and now it works ^^

Maybe the Storyboard thing could work if i add the namespace in the PropertyPath but i have no time to test it so give it a try if you want, and update the post ^^.